# SELECT inside IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT jargons.jargon as jargon, 
         jargons.description as description, 
         jargons.example as example,
         IF(jargons.rootJargon != 0, (SELECT jargon FROM jargons WHERE id = jargons.rootJargon), NULL) as rootJargonName
FROM jargons 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = jargons.addedBy 
ORDER BY jargons.id DESC
```

I have two rows inside jargons table:

```
"id"  "jargon"  "description"   "example"   "rootJargonName"    "rootJargon"
"2"   "Child"         "jd"           "1"             NULL                1
"1"    Root"          "sad"          "1"             NULL                0
```

Why does the `rootJargonName` returns `null` instead of `Root` on `Child` row?

What I was trying to do is that if `rootJargon` column is not equals to zero then select the row with the id that specified in the column which is not equals to zero.

Comment: Try adding a table alias to both of the `jargons` references - it's possible it's trying to compare the `id` and `rootJargon` from the same table reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely a table alias issue you're seeing, but you can rewrite this using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT      J.jargon as jargon, 
            J.description as description, 
            J.example as example,
            R.jargon As rootJargonName
FROM        jargons as J
LEFT JOIN   users   as U ON U.id = J.addedBy 
LEFT JOIN   jargons as R ON J.rootJargon = R.ID
ORDER BY    J.id DESC
```

If you would like to keep the `IF()` function, you can use the following, however I recommend using the `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT      J.jargon as jargon, 
            J.description as description, 
            J.example as example,
            IF(J.rootJargon != 0, (SELECT jargon FROM jargons as R WHERE R.id = J.rootJargon), NULL) as rootJargonName
FROM        jargons as J
LEFT JOIN   users   as U ON U.id = J.addedBy 
ORDER BY    J.id DESC
```

Comment: Well alright, this works. Isn't there any way to do this with IF statement? Just wondering.

Comment: @AliDemirci You can rewrite it using the `IF()` function, but this would cause a sub-query for each record returned.  It would be generally better to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for this, but I'll update the answer to include the `IF()` fix.

Comment: Now that's perfect answer. Thank you!

Comment: Wait a minute. What if I want to specify another value for nulls?

Comment: @AliDemirci If you want to specify another value for the `NULL` data, you can use the `COALESCE()` function.  E.g.: `COALESCE(R.jargon, 'OtherValue')`

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try a case

like:

```
SELECT jargons.jargon as jargon, 
     jargons.description as description, 
     jargons.example as example,
     CASE 
         WHEN (jargons.rootJargon == 0) THEN NULL
         WHEN (jargons.rootJargon != 0) THEN
         (SELECT jargon FROM jargons WHERE id = jargons.rootJargon)
     END) AS 'rootJargonName'
FROM jargons 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = jargons.addedBy 
ORDER BY jargons.id DESC
```

I'm probably wrong somewhere in the syntax but i think thats the idea....